# QTranslator translate to English

Tags: qt, localization, qtranslate

I have some troubles translating my application from Russian to English using QTranslator. That is a way i tried to do it:
1) my .pro file contains the following strings:

```
CODECFORTR = UTF-8
CODECFORSRC = UTF-8
TRANSLATIONS += app_en.ts
```

2) that is my main.cpp file:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;
    bool ok = translator.load(":/app_en.qm");
    ok = app.installTranslator(&translator);
    QLabel label(QObject::tr("Some text in Russian"));
    label.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

3) I have used **lupdate** to generate .ts file, than **linguist** to generate.qm file. But when I run my application russian text stays on Russian.
4) I also tried to swap languages - use English as source and than translate it to Russian using the same steps - everything works ok and I got correct translation. It seems that I didn't specify something to make Qt know i need to translate Russian (which is a native language for my system) to Englih. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to use trUtf8() instead of tr().

Comment: And, btw, better practice is to avoid using static calls to QObject::tr() because you lose context in ts files for such calls. Instead, you'd better use qApp->translate() in classes not derived from QObject.

Comment: @EvgenyS.unfortunatelly, that doesn't help. I use a call QObject::tr() just to demonstrate the problem, And trUtf8() is obsolete and not recommended for using (in qt5 at least).

Comment: Can you check what is the result of `translator.load()` and `app.installTranslator()` calls? I've just checked, on Qt 5.5 Windows mingw build both `QObject::tr("Привет мир") `and `qApp()->translate("testContext","Балалайка")` work just fine without extra efforts or settings. And, please, make sure that your c++ source  is in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @EvgenyS.both of these calls return true. Is it possible for you to send me a project you have tested?

Comment: How to attach an archive here?

Comment: @EvgenyS. I'm not sure if it is possible. Please, send it to mszimka@gmail.com

Comment: @EvgenyS.your project is translated well, thanks. I'll try to find solution for my own one.

Comment: My only guess is that your c++ file is not UTF-8. Try to go to Menu-Edit-Select Encoding and Reload and Save with UTF-8 encoding. Don't forget to regenerate ts and qm files and rebuild the project after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106508/discussion-between-mikhail-zimka-and-evgeny-s).